# Results from a iteration in a dataframe doesn't give expected result

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

I have the next code:

```
for country in list2fix:
  f=df.city_name.eq(country)
  x=df[f]
  y=x[['Lat','Long']]
  y.loc[:,'Lat']=np.radians(y.loc[:,'Lat'])
  y.loc[:,'Long']=np.radians(y.loc[:,'Long'])
  kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(y)
  kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

What i am trying is filter every element in the `list2fix=['Italy','Mexico'...]` from a dataframe that contain every city of a country, but i don't need all of the countries in a dataframe, just extract a few of them in a list and then apply k-means, but the results doesn't printed. What I got is a message:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1773:
> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
> value instead
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Italy_North'

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: check `df.dtypes` to see if you have numeric values in "Lat" and "Long"

Comment: `SettingWithCopyWarning` happens because you're assigning values to `y`, which is a copy of `x`.

Comment: Thanks. I've already convert all "Lat" and "Long" values of that dataframe and looks good.